# Xcode - how to disable pagecontrol?

Tags: iphone, uipagecontrol

I have 2 views which the user can scroll between. I have page control working so I have the 2 dots at the bottom of the page which show the current page. I want to be able to disable this if the user changes a setting. I can't seem to find the code to do this? I guess it would be nice if the 2 dots remained but were greyed out, but this isn't a must!

Any tips would be great :-)

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried setting the control's enabled property to NO?

```
myPageControl.enabled = NO;
```

Comment: that isn't doing anything, but it does seem sensible! Any more ideas? Maybe I need to refresh it or something after that line?

Comment: Is your ui designed in IB?  Make sure the IBOutlet is connected properly.

Comment: Figured it out, this works...  pageControl.hidden = YES; scrollView.scrollEnabled=NO; Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4, Swift 5

```
pageControl.isEnabled = false
```